# Android GCM Registration IDs

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I successfully implemented GCM in my Android app but how do I know when my application gets uninstalled from a device? I would to delete the registration id in my MySQL database as well. I think Apple has a service which checks for not responding id's when sending is failed but does Google has something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)

> Finally, when GCM attempts to deliver a message to the device and the
>   application was uninstalled, GCM will discard that message right away
>   and invalidate the registration ID. Future attempts to send a message
>   to that device will get a NotRegistered error. See How Unregistration
>   Works for more information.

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg)

Comment: But this only works if the app is running and you call the unregister method right? I dont believe this works when an application hasnt started and the user decides to delete the app through the settings menu

Comment: You're entirely correct, I've updated my answer and linked to the documentation for this scenario

Comment: Ahh thats what I thought! I just had some delay while testing it. It kept returning successful but got the error now. Going to fix this right away
Can accept answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Ideally what you can do is send registration ID and ANDROID_ID to your content management system(to your MySQL database).
And listen PACKAGE_REMOVED intent and inside broadcast receiver you can remove that particular registration ID from your MySQL database